# View list of object in ag-grid data table

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm using [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid). this is my `rowData` object:

```
{  
 "Name" : "aaa",
 "Family" : "ds"
 "Age" : "16",
 "Tests" : [ 
    {
        "TestName" : "bb",
        "TestResult" : "1234"
    }, 
    {
        "TestName" : "aa",
        "TestResult" : "4322"
    }
 ]
}
```

My Question is: how can I view **Tests** object as seperates columns - **TestName** will be the column name and **TestResult** will be the cell data?

My table should looks as follow:

[image]

Any idea for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the array inside object to be direct object properties so they can be rendered by ag-grid as column name and value.

```
const data = {  
"Name" : "aaa",
"Family" : "ds",
"Age" : "16",
"Tests" : [ 
    {
        "TestName" : "bb",
        "TestResult" : "1234"
    }, 
    {
        "TestName" : "aa",
        "TestResult" : "4322"
    }
]
}
const newData = {...data};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newData['Tests'])) {
    newData[value['TestName']] = value['TestResult']
}
delete(newData.Tests);
```

The newData should contain the array data as part of the object which should solve the problem.

```
{ Name: 'aaa', Family: 'ds', Age: '16', bb: '1234', aa: '4322' }
```

This is just an example and there can be edge cases like TestName may be same for multiple fields which will override the previous values.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answar!, after converting the json - how can i set the header name and filed?

Comment: You just need to pass the data once it is prepared. Just set the columns and rowdata with newData for aggrid.  Make sure field name matches. You can read about it from here. https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/getting-started/. Or please share a example of how you are setting the data for ag-grid so we can debug for any issues.

Comment: i'm setting grid column as follow: this.gridCol.push{ headerName: "Name", field: "Name" } - this in case i knew filed name. but now its adynamic object - and how can i know whats the header name?

Comment: @user you can simply set the header by iterating over the keys.

Comment: right, thats what i did:  for (var key in this.newRwoUpdate) {
          this.gridColumns.push({
            headerName: key,
            field: key,
            checkboxSelection: false,
            headerCheckboxSelection: false,
          });
        }  but the metter now that filed is not shown (i got only headers)

Answer (score 2):

@user. I have a demo for dynamic column headers.

```
var data = { Name: 'aaa', Family: 'ds', Age: '16', bb: '1234', aa: '4322' };
for(key in data){
  if(gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn(key)!= null){
    desktopDefaultCols.push({
                                             headerName: key,
                                             field: key,
                                           });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost answaring on my second question. header name is working but the filed is not recognized - any idea?

Comment: i think you are initializing error header, you can check by console.log(AllColumns). if there is a duplicate field name will = key +'_1'